# x11vnc change resolution

Tags: linux, desktop, resolution, x11vnc

I am using the following command to open up an `x11vnc` server on boot within crontab -e

```
@reboot /usr/bin/x11vnc -bg -reopen -forever
```

It works perfectly, but I would like to see if the following can be done...

- Specify which vnc port it uses. For example, 5910.
- Specify a resolution to use (it's currently quite small on my screen

I have looked at the documentation for all their flags but can't see anything that helps me so far, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Do you know you can create a service for vncserver?

Answer (score 8):

As per [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc), to specify VNC port to listen on, you can use `-rfbport str` option. Or use `-autoport n` to automatically probe for a free VNC port starting at *n* (e.g. 5900).

To specify the resolution, you can use `-clip WxH+X+Y` option to show only the sub-region of the full display. If it's too small, use `-scale fraction` or `-geometry WxH` to scale  the framebuffer (e.g. `-geometry 1024x768` or `-scale 0.9x0.75`).